# Show button in Customized table view ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, customization

i m new, i added this code to customize table view with image and button in row

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";
    UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
    UIImageView *photo;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0.0, 100, 20)];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

        photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 80.0, 45.0)];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;


        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];
   }

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"man.jpg"];
    photo.image = theImage;

    return cell;

}
```

image part coming in row of the table, but not the button .
what is the problem in it please

Comment: Please fix the code formatting.

Comment: try giving button title or backgrond color. Actually a Custom cell is good option

Comment: the problem is with the frame of the button. Part of the button is behind the imageView. Change the x-coordinate of the button to 150 and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it....

```
UIButton *finalPriceBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
finalPriceBtn.tag=i+200;
finalPriceBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0.0, 100, 20);
[finalPriceBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goBtnClk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
finalPriceBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[finalPriceBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f",tempVal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[finalPriceBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 2.0f/255.0f green: 155.0f/255.0f blue: 213.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[finalPriceBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 2.0f/255.0f green: 155.0f/255.0f blue: 213.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
finalPriceBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
[cell.contentView addSubview:finalPriceBtn];
```

Hope i helped.

Comment: how i only select the button click not the cell of table view

Comment: @user2256034 : -(IBAction)goBtnClk:(id)sender
{
    int i = [sender tag];
    i = i - 200; // Select button id
}

Comment: @user2256034 : What happened ?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the button and then adding the image, therefore the image is on top of the button, do this:

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];
```

Before this:

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding image above your button so add it below the button.

Use your code like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";
    UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
    UIImageView *photo;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 80.0, 45.0)];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0.0, 100, 20);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];// Here add some background color to check its visibility
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
   }

   UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"man.jpg"];
   photo.image = theImage;

    return cell;
}
```